# Reference for Garding's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, integral-inequality

Does anyone know which is the original paper in which **Garding's inequality** first appeared? By this, I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A5rding%27s_inequality.

Many thanks!

Comment: See [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-69850-2_19) reference.

Comment: many thanks! do you also happen to know the original reference for Korn's inequality?

Comment: Maybe [14]-[15] [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11401-010-0606-3).

Comment: wow. many thanks! i really wish i knew about this survey months ago.